# how to add require_once to a wordpress template file

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a wordpress template file. 
I need to require_once() a file path. Where should I put the code?

```
<?php require_once("phpChart/conf.php");?>
```

It is giving me errors if I put it in my template file. It doesn't seem to work either in the header.php file.

If I include it in the template file I can a ton of errors. I think it needs to be in the header before the html. 
Here are some of the errors:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in /xxx/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 262 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0003283432{main}( ).../index.php:0 20.0004287208require( '/xxx/wp-blog-header.php' ).../index.php:17 30.454546621040require_once( '/xxx/wp-includes/template-loader.php' ).../wp-blog-header.php:16 40.459646824600include( '/xxx/wp-content/themes/gazette-child/email.php' ).../template-loader.php:74 50.537247474312get_header( ).../email.php:18 60.537547477952locate_template( ).../general-template.php:45 70.537547478144load_template( ).../template.php:477 80.537747516408require_once( '/xxx/wp-content/themes/gazette-child/header.php' ).../template.php:501 90.581648215152the_excerpt( ).../header.php:56 100.581648215264get_the_excerpt( ).../post-template.php:336 110.581748215672apply_filters( ).../post-template.php:367 120.581748217056call_user_func_array:{/xxx/wp-includes/plugin.php:213} ( ).../plugin.php:213 130.581748217088wp_trim_excerpt( ).../plugin.php:213 140.581748217248get_the_content( ).../formatting.php:2609 " /> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in /xxx/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 262 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0003283432{main}( ).../index.php:0 20.0004287208require( '/xxx/wp-blog-header.php' ).../index.php:17 30.454546621040require_once( '/xxx/wp-includes/template-loader.php' ).../wp-blog-header.php:16 40.459646824600include( '/xxx/wp-content/themes/gazette-child/email.php' ).../template-loader.php:74 50.537247474312get_header( ).../email.php:18 60.537547477952locate_template( ).../general-template.php:45 70.537547478144load_template( ).../template.php:477 80.537747516408require_once( '/xxx/wp-content/themes/gazette-child/header.php' ).../template.php:501 90.585448229760the_excerpt( ).../header.php:68 100.585448229840get_the_excerpt( ).../post-template.php:336 110.585448230048apply_filters( ).../post-template.php:367 120.585448231280call_user_func_array:{/xxx/wp-includes/plugin.php:213} ( ).../plugin.php:213 130.585448231312wp_trim_excerpt( ).../plugin.php:213 140.585448231392get_the_content( ).../formatting.php:2609 - http://xxx/email/">
```

Comment: What are the errors? Have you tried functions.php?

Comment: I tried wp_enqueue_script('phpChart/conf.php'); in the functions.php file but the class isn't loading

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script` is for loading javascript not php files.

Answer (score 1):

Use `require_once()` or `include()` to include a file. You didn't post what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

`require('phpChart/conf.php');` in `functions.php` worked.